# Finding files older than x amount of days in PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell

I am trying to find files older than two years in my shared drive but my date comparison does not work.  It displays all the files in the folder ignoring that is supposed to find only files older than 750 days.  This is the code I have:

```
    $Path = "\\server\folder"
    $datetime = (Get-Date).AddDays(-750)
    
    Get-ChildItem -File $Path -Force -Recurse 
`| Where-Object {$_.LastAccessTime -lt $datetime} 
`| Select @{Name="Owner"; Expression={(Get-ACL $_.Fullname).Owner}}, lastaccesstime, directory, name
```

If someone can spot what I am missing I will be very thankful if you let me know.

Comment: Maybe you should consider `where { $_.CreationTime -lt $datetime }` instead.

Comment: Thanks a million AdminOfThings.  That seems to be working.

Comment: Also try out `LastWriteTime`. The `CreationTime` is not always what it seems.. A file may have been copied to a new location and then the creationtime property is set to the time the copy took place. LastWriteTime is the time the file got created/updated last.